# Masterpage concept for plain HTML

Tags: html

I got a realtive big project for what I have many plain HTML pages. All the pages have the same template, but when I change one value in the template I have to change all the other pages manually.

Is there a way to do it like less for CSS or CoffeeScript for JS?

Lg Knerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have are plain HTML pages you could use SSI although it is a bit dated and youll need to be running this on a web server like Apache.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Personally I would use php so I could just include the files with the php include function

Comment: Thx, I will evaluate this. In the backend I got an IIS, so this is no problem. I use a plain HTML and JS site, because in the backend there is an WCF Service and so I can use just REST with jQuery.ajax. It is much easier than write a whole ASP.net page. I don't like PHP and I don't "speak" PHP ;)

Comment: `<?php include 'myfile.html'; ?>` is all you would need :)

Comment: This little PHP I know ^^ But the only serverlogic I got is the WCF Service. And with HTML5 FileAPI etc. I can also Upload files :)

Comment: Ok, I have to correct myself... SSI #if only works in the apache server, but I got an IIS and want to deploy the project on Windows Azure, any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry I dont know SSI in that depth, you could try another solution like PHP or perhaps post another question on using SSI `#if` on an IIS server.

Comment: `#if` don't works in IIS, I used an asp.net MasterPage solution, it works great ;) And anothertime, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Knerd, I am at same place where you were. How did you used Masterpage with asp.net. Did you contentpage tag in child pages?